# Is it possible to apply device dependent security trimming?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, security, mobile, security-trimming

With SP2013, is it possible to apply additional restrictions to what can be viewed by a user using a mobile device (specifically Windows Phone) as opposed to a desktop or laptop?

We can assume that the device is issued by the business (not BYOD) and hasn't been tampered with (so user-agent strings, etc will be as expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sharepoint 2013, you have `device channels` which exactly do the same thing you need.

> Device Channels is a mechanism that allows you to define a number of channels, map them to devices using user agent matches or custom logic, and associate different Master Pages to each channel.

For more details on this check below links:

1. [Device Channel in SP 2013](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/device-channels-sharepoint-2013/)
2. [Optimizing SharePoint 2013 websites for mobile devices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/05/07/optimizing-sharepoint-2013-websites-for-mobile-devices.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that partly answers my question.  However Device Channels only apply to Publishing Sites.  Is there a similar way to handle other sites, such as those containing lists and libraries?

Comment: In that case your only option is responsive web design. Check this http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/responsive-web-design-v-device-channels-in-sharepoint-2013/